# Solution for running REACT web app on (visual studio)code-server behind the proxy situation

Tags: reactjs, code-server

When we develop web app with VS code-server, the default method to preview the result URL is

http://{yoursite}/proxy/3000

However, it does not work with react development.

When we follow the official tutorial to start a react app, all the static resources inside the html template always redirected to the index.html

e.g index.html is returned instead of /static/js/bundle.js

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this problem, in the project root directory, open:

package.json

In script block,change the start property

from:

"start": "react-scripts start"

to

"start" : "**PUBLIC_URL='/absproxy/3000'** react-scripts start"
:

```js
  "scripts": {
    
    "start": "PUBLIC_URL='/absproxy/3000/' react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

This is also written in below documentation.
https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/guide#stripping-proxyport-from-the-request-path

Answer (score 1):

for those who has an another app running on port 3000, just simply do these little steps:

optional:

`export PORT=3001`

and then add in package.json

```
"scripts": {    
"start": "PUBLIC_URL='/absproxy/3001/' react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

if you are running a ***Nextjs App*** you should do provide a basePath:

go to **next.confing.js** file and just add this line of code:

```
basePath:"/absproxy/3002"
```